# WordPress Api error: "Sorry, you are not allowed to create new posts."

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, google-apps-script

I'm using the current Apps script function to add a new post to my WordPress site:

```
 var um_url = 'http://test.mywebsite.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/posts';
 var um_headers = { 
    "Accept" : "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Basic "+Utilities.base64Encode("user:passowrd"),
    "Content-type":"application/json"
        };

 var um_options = {  
   "method":"POST",     
   "headers": um_headers,
   "dataType" : 'json',
   "data": {
     title: "Foo title",
     content: "Foo content",
     status: "publish"
    }

    };

  var um_response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(um_url, um_options);
  var json = um_response.getContentText();
  Logger.log(json);
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
 {"code":"rest_cannot_create","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to create new posts.","data":{"status":401}}
```

I read other similar StackOverflow questions and they solved it by changing the `.htacess` file, unfortunately, this didn't solve my issue.
here is my `.htaccess` file

```
# BEGIN WP BASIC Auth
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
</IfModule>
# END WP BASIC Auth



# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [E=X-HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%        {HTTP:Authorization},QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [E=X-HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},QSA,L]
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried installing the basic-auth plugin?

Comment: I did, but no progress - I assume the plugin can't help me because this is the newest WP (5.2.2)

Comment: Are you authenticated?

Answer (score 0):

I just had almost exactly the same problem, trying to add something through REST API.   The trick is that you need to send the REST WP Nonce (named wp_rest) through with the request, as either a header, or as part of the request variable...

if you use fetch, you can do this...

```
fetch( route, {
    method: method, 
    headers: {
        'X-WP-Nonce': wpApiSettings.nonce
    }
} )
```

or add it to your query vars as **'_wpnonce'**

You can find the code that is setting the current user to 0 at `wp-includes/rest-api.php` on **line 834 (ver 5.2.1)**

Comment: how to call api to get nonce for adding new custom post, say 'book' ?

Comment: It gives me the error:     "code": "rest_cookie_invalid_nonce",
    "message": "Cookie nonce is invalid",
    "data": {
        "status": 403
    }

Answer (score -1):

It is due to `status: "publish"` in your data object. Change it to `status: "pending"` and it will work. This happens because users can't directly publish the post unless they have a role of `author` or above.

You can either change your code as follow (OR) change user's role to `author` and set `New User Default Role` to `Author` under `WordPress settings » General` for new users as well.

```js
 var um_url = 'http://test.mywebsite.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/posts';
 var um_headers = { 
    "Accept" : "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Basic "+Utilities.base64Encode("user:passowrd"),
    "Content-type":"application/json"
        };

 var um_options = {  
   "method":"POST",     
   "headers": um_headers,
   "dataType" : 'json',
   "data": {
     title: "Foo title",
     content: "Foo content",
     status: "pending"
    }

    };

  var um_response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(um_url, um_options);
  var json = um_response.getContentText();
  Logger.log(json);
}
```